# Cannot serialize the derived property to JSON in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, json.net

I am trying to GET an object of this type (through Web API):

```
public class Document 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public FileFolder Folder { get; set; }
    public FileFolder FolderParent 
    {
        get
        {
            return FileFolder.Folder;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

"Error getting value from 'FolderParent' on 'Domain.Document'."

Comment: What does your Folder class look like.  Seems like you must have a typo in your example because you can't even compile a class Public Folder with a member of name Folder.

Comment: Changed the names already, that is not the actual code actually

Comment: Advice: give a different name in your method because yo have a Object (Folder) with the same name.

Comment: It Compile? you should have an error like: Inconsistent accesibility: property type 'namespacename.FileFolder' is lessaccesible than property 'namespacename.Document.FolderParent' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a quick little example together and it serialized fine.  Seems like the bug must be coming from somewhere in the design of your FileFolder class which we don't have right now.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest8
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestJasonFileFolder()
    {
        var folder = new FileFolder();
        folder.Folder = new FileFolder { Name = "Parent" };
        folder.Name = "Something";

        var document = new Document { Folder = folder, Id = 1 };

        var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
        Assert.IsNotNull(test);
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public FileFolder Folder { get; set; }
    public FileFolder FolderParent
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Folder.Folder;
        }
    }
}

public class FileFolder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FileFolder Folder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is JsonConvert that serializes, but I think its the default serializer(to JSON) in Web API. I put this lines of code in my WebApiConfig.cs: var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

Comment: Well you can certainly take the unit test I provided and use it with your particular code base.  If JsonConvert.Serialize works then we know it's a config/Web API problem. If it does throw the same error then we know it's some kind of problem with FileFolder class.

Comment: I tried and it passed. So maybe there's something wrong with my Web API configration